# Getting Stage coordinates of Actor in Table in libGDX

Tags: java, coordinates, libgdx

I want to create a floating help bubble to introduce the basic functioning of my game. This bubble should float above the Actor I want it to explain, like shown in the picture below.

[image: Floating instruction bubble.]

To accomplish this, I want the coordinates of the Actor, in this case the left button, and then I can add the bubble Actor to the Stage in front of everything else. The last part is easy enough, but I'm struggling with retrieving the actual coordinates of the button, as it is in a table.

The two buttons are added to a Table like this:

```
t.add(btnLab).expandX().center();
t.add(btnSea).expandX().center();
```

I've tried the most obvious approach:

```
Vector2 loc = new Vector2(a.getX(), a.getY());
System.out.println("Loc: " + loc);
a.localToStageCoordinates(loc);
System.out.println("Loc: " + loc);
```

This gives me (in the order of the sysouts): [0.0, 0.0] and [40.0, 130.0]. The last position is actually the position of the Table, which fills the blue area of the screen. So this location obviously misses something the Table does to place the Actor, and cannot be used (as I only end up with the location of the Table).

(I've also tried using t.localToStageCoordinates here, t being the Table. Same results.)

Another solution I tried was to recursively search through all Parents:

```
private static Vector2 getLoc(Actor a) {
    return getLoc(new Vector2(a.getX(), a.getY()), a.getParent());
}

private static Vector2 getLoc(Vector2 loc, Actor g) {
    System.out.println("Location: " + loc + ", Actor: " + g);
    loc.x += g.getX();
    loc.y += g.getY();
    if(g.getParent() == null) return loc;
    return getLoc(loc, g.getParent());
}
```

Unfortunately, this gives me the same. The sysouts gives the following:

```
Location: [0.0:0.0], Actor: Table 40.0,130.0 944.0x508.0
Location: [40.0:130.0], Actor: Group 0.0,0.0 0.0x0.0
Location: [40.0:130.0], Actor: Group 0.0,0.0 0.0x0.0
```

So I can't seem to get the actual positions of the Groups/Actors within the Table.

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: In addition to my answer, I'm wondering if you are trying to get the position of the actor prior to the first time the actors are rendered? If you try to get the location before the framework has had time to correctly do a layout you will be getting the wrong coords. In my example I alleviate this by using an event listener to  get the correct position after the layout has been performed.

Comment: I have a `Table` inside a `VerticalGroup` inside another `Table` in my `Stage`. I followed the below answer, but it did not work. The problem ended up being that the elements were not laid out before I assigned the starting table position. None of the stage location translation in that answer was necessary. `table.getX()` got me the location in the stage that I needed once I did it after the layout happened.

Comment: @Jyro117 Thanks for that tip. I was having the same issue. Took a long time to realize that I may be calculating actor positions too early.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think I understand where you got confused. It is actually very simple to get the stage coordinates of an actor (assuming screen aligned, unrotated, unscaled actors).

All you need to do is this:

```
public static Vector2 getStageLocation(Actor actor) {
    return actor.localToStageCoordinates(new Vector2(0, 0));
}
```

What you are doing wrong is trying to get the location of the actor relative to the table (by using actor.getX() and actor.getY()), and then transform that location to the stage. That will end up giving you the location of table because it will be adding the location of the actor. What you really what is to know where point new Vector2(0, 0) inside your actor is. This tells you where the bottom left corner of the actor is. If you want top left you would use new Vector2(0, actor.getHeight()), and the other corners in a similar manner.

Additionally, if you are working with events and want to know the stage location of an event you would simply do the following:

```
@Override public void touchUp(final InputEvent event, final float x, final float y, final int pointer, final int button) {
    if (pointer == Buttons.LEFT) {
        Gdx.app.log("Event", "x: " + event.getStageX() + " y: " + event.getStageY());
    }
}
```

For a more complete example look at the following code:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener;

public class ActorStage implements ApplicationListener {
    private Stage stage;
    private Skin skin;

    @Override public void create() {
        Gdx.app.log("CREATE", "App Opening");

        this.stage = new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this.stage);

        this.skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/uiskin.json"));
        this.skin.hashCode();

        final Table table = new Table();
        table.setFillParent(true);

        final Button btnLab = new TextButton("Lab", skin);
        final Button btnSea = new TextButton("Sea", skin);


        setupButton(table, btnLab);
        setupButton(table, btnSea);

        this.stage.addActor(table);

        Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1);
        Gdx.gl20.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    }

    private void setupButton(Table table, final Button button) {
        table.add(button).expandX().center();

        button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                Gdx.app.log("XY", "[" + x + ", " + y + "]");
                Gdx.app.log("Event", "[" + event.getStageX() + ", " + event.getStageY() + "]");
                Gdx.app.log("Actor", "[" + button.getX() + ", " + button.getY() + "]");

                Vector2 loc = new Vector2(button.getX(), button.getY());
                Vector2 stageLoc = button.localToStageCoordinates(loc);
                Gdx.app.log("ActorStage", "[" + stageLoc.x + ", " + stageLoc.y + "]");

                Vector2 zeroLoc = button.localToStageCoordinates(new Vector2());
                Gdx.app.log("ZeroStage", "[" + zeroLoc.x + ", " + zeroLoc.y + "]");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override public void render() {
        this.stage.act();

        Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);

        this.stage.draw();
    }

    @Override public void dispose() {
        Gdx.app.log("DISPOSE", "App Closing");
    }

    @Override public void resize(final int width, final int height) {
        Gdx.app.log("RESIZE", width + "x" + height);
        Gdx.gl20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        this.stage.setViewport(width, height, false);
    }

    @Override public void pause() {}

    @Override public void resume() {}
}
```

When clicking btnLab once, clicking btnSea once and then closing the window, outputs:

```
CREATE: App Opening
RESIZE: 800x600
XY: [18.0, 13.0]
Event: [200.0, 296.0]
Actor: [182.0, 283.0]
ActorStage: [364.0, 566.0]
ZeroStage: [182.0, 283.0]
XY: [6.0, 23.0]
Event: [588.0, 306.0]
Actor: [582.0, 283.0]
ActorStage: [1164.0, 566.0]
ZeroStage: [582.0, 283.0]
DISPOSE: App Closing
```

As you can see you want the "ZeroStage" message because that gives you the location of the actor on the stage.

Comment: The question shows that the output of `a.getX(), a.getY()` is `0,0`, so wouldn't that mean the OP is already doing exactly what you suggest?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a full example showing that 0,0 does give you the stage coords. The OP may be doing something different to cause his output to be different.

Comment: Haha, yeah, zeros did the trick! That was stupid. Thank you for that, and for the very comprehensive answer.

Comment: No worries, I remember a long time ago fighting with this same issue. :)

Comment: hhm, doesn't work for me. I have Image inside Table and Table inside Stage. I use localToStageCoordinates(new Vector2()) on the image, but it returns me wrong coordinates. I use libgdx 1.1.0

Comment: This works for me but only after the Table and Stage have been drawn. If I request for the locations during the initial setup, it returns unusual coordinates